# How to build has_many :through relationship between the same Model (User) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I want to build many-to-many relationship between the same Model (User).

I have User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :broker_clients
  has_many :clients, :through => :broker_clients    
end
```

And BrokerClient:

```
class BrokerClients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
end
```

When I use rails console and do something like:

```
>> User.first.clients
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant User::BrokerClient
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:125:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:178:in `klass'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `block in source_reflection'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `collect'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `source_reflection'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:557:in `check_validity!'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:26:in `initialize'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `clients'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'>>
```

What I'm doing wrong here to get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::BrokerClient
```

Comment: Taking a look at your broker clients, it doesn't make much sense. It would usually be `belongs_to :broker, class_name: 'User'` and `belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User'`. Then the `User` would `has_many :clients, through: :broker_clients`.

Comment: Well, Client and Broker are subclasses of User. I modified BrokerClient : class BrokerClients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"
end
 But still getting the same error.

Comment: Your class should be singular. `class BrokerClient` if your table is `broker_clients`. ActiveRecord is looking for the appropriate class based on your table name and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Changed class BrokerClients -> BrokerClient but sill getting this error: NameError: uninitialized constant User::BrokerClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :broker_clients, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "broker_id"
  has_many :clients, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "client_id"

  #Your class definition here...
end
```

Access clients and broker_clients via:

```
   clients =  User.first.clients
   broker_clients = User.first.broker_clients
```

Comment: has_many clients without :through => :broker_clients ?? How would I relate to broker_clients table ?

Comment: I don't want to access broker_clients, I just want to access clients through broker_clients table.

Comment: My idea was to keep both clients and broker_clients in the same table, without 2nd table. It a little bit de normalize your table, but also could be a solution.

Comment: You are right, and I appreciate your help. But how would I do the same with has_many :through relationship. I prefer to have a separate table for the relationships as I will need it to store other data.